# Audio Signal Processing & DHT

Tags: matlab

Is there any matlab (default) function for Discrete Hartley Transform? And is it applicable for audio signal? I want to apply it instead of DWT or FFT.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no in-build MATLAB function for DHT, but you can implement it very easily using the `fft` function:

```
function H=dht(x)
    X = fft(x);
    H = real(X) - imag(X);
end
```

Answer (score 1):

The links betwwen Fourier and Hartley are discussed in [Hartley Transform vs Fourier Transform](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/34682/15892).

The quick FFT-based implementation can be found for instance in [`dht.m`](https://github.com/emtiajium/ThesisWatermarking/blob/master/SourceCode/dht.m). I do not know of a native Matlab version. One reason could be that the Discrete Hartley transform is not so efficient in practice, as discussed in an answer to [Hartley Transform vs Fourier Transform](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/34682/15892). Other references are in:

- [function X = my_DHT(x)](https://fr.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/55425-digital-signal-processing-survival-kit?focused=5956251&tab=function)
- [Fast algorithms of Fourier and Hartley transform and their implementation in Matlab](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.52.8338&rep=rep1&type=pdf), by Vítìzslav Veselý