# Fast Hartley Transform Implementation in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, discrete-signals, fourier-transform, dft, reference-implementation

I want to implement [Fast Hartley Transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hartley_transform) (Specifically [Discrete Hartley Transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_Hartley_transform)) in a script file in MATLAB. Does anyone know have a reference implementation of this in MATLAB or another language so that a complete novice can understand it?

Comment: if you ask me, that makes little to no sense. The fact that you can save quite a few operation with the FHT will be immensely outweighed by the fact that you're doing this within matlab's interpreter – which is notoriously slow. Things like the FFT are implemented in highly-optimized native code, not in matlab scripts. Any matlab-script FFT would be much, much slower than just doing the DFT naively by multiplying with a DFT matrix (because matrix multiplication is, again, implemented natively). takeaway:matlab itself is very slow.If you need fast,implement natively and call from within matlab.

Comment: **Note:** Today there is no reason to expect the Hartley transform to be faster than a real-to-complex FFT. A long time ago it might have been faster, but that is no longer the case. See for example [this warning in the FFTW docs](https://www.fftw.org/fftw3_doc/The-Discrete-Hartley-Transform.html).

Answer (score 4):

You can resort to the properties of the DHT with the DFT, given in the [wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hartley_transform#Relation_to_Fourier_transform). For a real-valued function $f$, its DHT in terms of the DFT is given by

$$
\mathcal{H}f = \Re\{\mathcal{F}f\}-\Im\{\mathcal{F}f\}.
$$

So, a function for fast Hartley transform can be given by

```
function Hf = fht(f)
F = fft(f);
Hf = real(F) - imag(F);
end
```

Though, you need to take care of the normalization factors, and tdhis is up to you and how you define the scale factors of the DHT.

Comment: Make the answer complete by adding the inverse transform. Good answer!

Comment: @Royi The Hartley transform is its own inverse. `fht(fht(f)) == f`.

Comment: @CrisLuengo, Indeed. Just thought it makes sense to express it as part of the answer.

Answer (score 3):

For the standard algorithmic version, you can get information in [An Algorithm for the Fast Hartley transform](http://sep.stanford.edu/data/media/public/oldreports/sep38/38_29.pdf), R. F. Ulmann (with Fortran versions). A [Matlab version of the FHT is provided by Lars Gregersen](https://fr.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/7629), exactly as given by @MaximilianMatthé, except that it checks for a real signal input. 
C++ and C# versions can also be found in [ALGLIB: Fast Hartley transform](http://www.alglib.net/fasttransforms/fht.php).

For improved versions, that can provide speed-up beyond algorithmic optimization, one can consider other factors, such as memory tricks, hardware optimization, use of binary inputs/outputs, higher-dimension extensions. You can check for instance:

- [A Novel Split-Radix Fast Algorithm for 2-D Discrete Hartley Transform](https://doi.org/10.1109/TCSI.2009.2028639), 2009
- [Binary Discrete Cosine and Hartley Transforms](https://doi.org/10.1109/TCSI.2012.2224751), 2013