# How to compute convolution using the Discrete Hartley Transform

Tags: fft, discrete-signals, signal-analysis, python, convolution

It's easy to compute the [Discrete Hartley Transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_Hartley_transform) of a 1D signal:

```
import numpy as np

def dht(x:np.array):    
    X = np.fft.fft(x)
    X = np.real(X) - np.imag(X)
    return X

def idht(X:np.array):
    n = len(X)
    X = dht(X)
    x = 1/n * x
    return X
```

The code for `dht` is based on [this answer](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/25604/audio-signal-processing-dht), while `idht` uses the involutory property of the DHT (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_Hartley_transform#Properties)) .

However, when I try to compute the *circular convolution* of two sequences using the well-known property of the DHT shown [here](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/55166/convolution-in-the-hartley-domain), I get absurd results. What am I doing wrong? Here is the code...

```
def conv(x:np.array, y:np.array):
    X = dht(x)
    Y = dht(y)
    Xflip = np.flip(X)
    Yflip = np.flip(Y)
    Yplus = Y + Yflip
    Yminus = Y - Yflip
    Z = 0.5 * (X * Yplus + Xflip * Yminus)
    z = idht(Z)
    return z


def test_conv():
    x = np.ones((5, ))
    y = np.copy(x)
    z = conv(x, y)
    z1 = np.real(np.fft.ifft(np.fft.fft(x)*np.fft.fft(y)))
    np.testing.assert_allclose(z, z1, err_msg="test_convolution() failed")


if (__name__=='__main__'):
    test_conv()
    print("test_conv passed")
```

The code output is below: `x` is the circular convolution as computed by my code, and `y` is the circular convolution as computed by FFT.

```
AssertionError: 
Not equal to tolerance rtol=1e-07, atol=0
test_convolution() failed
Mismatched elements: 5 / 5 (100%)
Max absolute difference: 5.65018378
Max relative difference: 1.13003676
 x: array([ 0.      ,  4.105099,  5.992006,  3.053079, -0.650184])
 y: array([5., 5., 5., 5., 5.])
```

Comment: you say you get "absurd" results, what are these?

Comment: Please provide sample input and the "absurd" output that it generates

Comment: @tobassist the sample input is included in the code. For the output, run the code.

Comment: @MarcusMüller I modified the code and the question extensively, but the results still don't make sense, even now I compute the circular convolution.

Comment: @tobassist I modified the question and included the output.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't know the convolution theorem for the DHT before, but it's pretty clear that if it exists, it must be about *circular* convolution, just like for the DFT.

You're comparing that with acyclic convolution, so the results differing is no surprise.

Comment: ouch! Thanks for the pointer. Is there a `numpy` function to compute cyclic convolution, so that I can test the correctness of my code?

Comment: implementing that in a `for` loop doesn't sound so bad, honestly.

Comment: do you mean implementing cyclic convolution in a `for` loop?

Comment: yes, that's what I mean.

Comment: hmmm. For a unit test I'd rather use an existing, well-tested function from a known library, than writing code myself. Anyway, can you add an implementation of circular convolution as a `for` loop to your question? Or should I ask a new question?

Comment: seriously, if you can't trust yourself to write the convolution, you can't trust yourself to write a correct unit test, so get over it and write it :)

Comment: A reference for circular convolution would be `z = ifft(fft(x).*fft(y))` (MATLAB syntax)

Comment: @Hilmar that's an actually useful comment: I came to the same conclusion in meantime. Just as a curiosity, do you have a link to the definition of circular convolution for finite-length sequences? Thanks!

Comment: @DeltaIV um. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution#Circular_discrete_convolution

Comment: there was an error in my code, and it wasn't even computing the circular convolution, actually. Now I'm comparing circular convolution computed using the DHT, with circular convolution computed using the FFT. They still don't match.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to roll the array after flipping. What you want is `x0, x(n-1), x(n-1)... x2, x1` but you are using `x(n-1),x(n-2),... x1, x0` instead.

Change

```
Xflip = np.flip(X)
Yflip = np.flip(Y)
```

to this

```
Xflip = np.roll(np.flip(X),1)
Yflip = np.roll(np.flip(Y),1)
```

to get the correct convolution.